# Simple Probability Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, random-walk

Question:

Consider a simple model that predicts whether you pass your next test or not based on the result of your previous test. If you pass your previous test, then you have 0.2 chance you will pass your upcoming test. If you fail your previous test, then you have 0.5 chance you will fail your upcoming test. If it continues over a long time, what is the probability that you will pass a test?

I have calculated the eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors of P, but I don't know where to go after that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just as an aside, those are some mighty odd transition probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're on the right track. Assuming you've set up the `2x2` matrix that represents the transitions correctly, then you're all set. Recall that the long-run distribution is interpreted as the stationary probability vector, which is the left eigenvector of the transition matrix `P` associated with eigenvalue 1.

Comment: I've got the egienvalue 1, and the eigenvector is $\vec{w} = [-0.53, -0.848] $, what do you mean when you say "left" eigenvector?

Comment: i mean the vector $\pi$ such that $\pi P = \pi$, so $\pi$ is on the left side of $P$, which is your transition matrix. This is not the same as $P\pi = \pi$.